# Differences between text in link and input/button

Tags: css

How to remove the difference displaying buttons in Firefox and Chrome?

Case:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTjtg/9/)

Comment: Please paste the code here. jsFiddle is known to be incredibly slow to load sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reset the styles for Fx' `-moz-focus-inner` pseudo-element:

```
.btnViolet::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Here is a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/XTjtg/25/

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions posted for this have accessibility problems - they completely remove the focus outline.

To fix the padding but have the focus work the same as other links, try this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

button:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}
```